# Windows subnetmask, what's the use?

Tags: networking, subnet

I'm in a company network where we're using two subnets: 192.168.0.* and 192.168.3.*. These are my IP's:

- 192.168.0.97: PC / testserver host
- 192.168.0.108: laptop
- 192.168.3.192: mobile phone

The subnet mask on all these devices is set to 255.255.255.0

In the router we've configured all traffic to 192.168.0.97 to be allowed, as this is required for testing.

Pinging works between these devices:

- 192.168.0.97 - 192.168.0.108
- 192.168.0.97 - 192.168.3.192

It does not work on this one:

- 192.168.0.108 - 192.168.3.192

My question comes in here though: why can 192.168.0.97 ping 192.168.3.192? I know we've configured this in the server, but shouldn't the fact that windows has the subnet mask set to 255.255.255.0 prevent this?

So why can I ping across subnets? Apparently what I thought they were is false, so what are subnets for?

Comment: What exactly have you configured in the router? You are right, the subnet config should prevent the ping. But may routers that support multiple subnets also support routing between them. For me it seems like you enabled routing between these subnets in the router. (in other words: would you use only a switch, I would be sure the ping would not work)

Comment: This post on our sistersite [sf] might be worth reading:
http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subnets are as their name states *sub networks*.

Using numeric adddressing you can create **small networks** that connect to other small networks through **routers**. Having small networks is more **efficient** that a huge network encompassing all the millions PCs and servers in the world.

On IP protocol you can define the **scope** of a subnet by the use of a subnet mask, for example 255.255.255.0 means that the first 3 octets identify the **network** and the last one identify the **hosts** inside that subnet.

Traffic on the subnet never gets out of the subnet, except when it is **explicitly directed** outside, for example a ping from one subnet to the other.

Routers are devices that can connect two or more subnets together allowing traffic (pings, for example) to pass throught it from one subnet to the other. They act transparently to the traffic, however most of them can use firewall-like rules that let the router block types of traffic (HTTP, Ping, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

To complement the answer given by jcbermu

I just figured out how my pc actually communicates with my phone. The difference becomes clear when running tracert. The two outputs of this command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert 192.168.0.108

Tracing route to ***** [192.168.0.108]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  ***** [192.168.0.108]

Trace complete.
```

---

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert 192.168.3.192

Tracing route to 192.168.3.192 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms     3 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.249
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.4.248
  3   319 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.3.192

Trace complete.
```

Indeed my pc does not communicate with a different subnet. It's the router that does that. My pc itself has no connection to my phone, all gets redirected by the (apparently two) routers in between.

Comment: I don't mind being downvoted, but could the downvoter please explain why this would have to be downvoted? Would this answer not be helpful for others in trying to understand subdomains?